# Verifying a PBKDF2 password hash in python-pbkdf2

Tags: python, encryption, pbkdf2

I am using the snippet below to encrypt user password before saving in the database.

```
from pbkdf2 import crypt
pwhash = crypt(password_from_user)
```

Example: `$p5k2$$Y0qfZ64u$A/pYO.3Mt9HstUtEEhWH/RXBg16EXDMr`

Then, I save this in database. Well locally, I can perform a check doing something like this:

```
from pbkdf2 import crypt
  pwhash = crypt("secret")
  alleged_pw = raw_input("Enter password: ")
  if pwhash == crypt(alleged_pw, pwhash):
      print "Password good"
  else:
      print "Invalid password"
```

but how do I perform checks with what is on the db as the encrypted string is not always the same. I'm using [python-pbkdf2](https://www.dlitz.net/software/python-pbkdf2/).

Comment: https://www.dlitz.net/software/python-pbkdf2/

Comment: What do you mean by *"is not always the same"*? Does the verification work only sometimes or does it always work for some passwords, but not for others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, Did more research and figured out that to achieve this, i first have to encrypt the password and save in db.as:

```
pwhash = crypt("secret",iterations=1000)
```

which can produce a string like `$p5k2$3e8$her4h.6b$.p.OE5Gy4Nfgue4D5OKiEVWdvbxBovxm`

and to validate when a user wants to login with same password, i use the function below:

```
def isValidPassword(userPassword,hashKeyInDB):
     result = crypt(userPassword,hashKeyInDB,iterations = 1000)
     return reesult == hashKeyInDB #hashKeyInDB in this case is $p5k2$3e8$her4h.6b$.p.OE5Gy4Nfgue4D5OKiEVWdvbxBovxm
```

this method returns `True` if the password is same or `False` if otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Since python 3.4 you can use the built in `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac` to generate/check pbkdf2 hashes. Here is an example using PBKDF2 with HMAC(sha1):

```
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
import os
iterations=10000
salt = os.urandom(8) # b'\xd0A,3?\xc5\xe7\xfd' / bytes.fromhex('d0412c333fc5e7fd')
hash = pbkdf2_hmac('sha1',b'secret', salt, iterations, dklen=64).hex()
print(f"pbkdf2:{iterations}:{salt.hex()}:{hash}")
# pbkdf2:10000:d0412c333fc5e7fd:85c5ed63e0a80dc314a3134098d6ecb2facba6a9572bd7795ca9213864ff14245e5ea2787f6af1f4835005a1daa0c555b2f3e9af8dbb3db4ac8ed99fa448503b
```